# Nothing happens when I click on page on GridView with paging

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, gridview, paging, sqldatasource

I'm new to C# and .NET, but stuck on this for a couple days now, I am using MVC 3 (.NET 4.0) Web Application.

I looked through tutorials to make a GridView based on a SqlDataSource with the code below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
            OnPageIndexChanging = "GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="LastName,FirstName"
            EnablePersistedSelection="True" SelectedRowStyle-BackColor="Yellow" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowSorting="True" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="FirstName" />
                ...
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM User WHERE [IsDeleted]=0"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

However, when I click on the different pages, nothing happens(it looked like it reloaded the same page), but when I open in a new tab in Chrome, it just opens a blank page, when I hover over the link "2" to go to page 2, this is what shows:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridView1','Page$2')
```

When I click on the title to do a sort, nothing happens just as the pages, and the link says this:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridView1','Sort$WindowsUsername')
```

I've also tried putting on top of the aspx file this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.master" Inherits="..." %>
<script runat="server">

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
</script>
```

And same problem. This function isn't even being called when I click on other pages

Am I missing something somewhere? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the event for `OnPageIndexChanging` in your .aspx, which you don't have. It should be:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        OnPageIndexChanging = "GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="LastName,FirstName"
        EnablePersistedSelection="True" SelectedRowStyle-BackColor="Yellow" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowSorting="True">
```

Comment: Sorry I actually had that in my original code, forgot to paste that in. Will put it in.

Comment: Where and how are you binding the gridview?

Comment: It is binded through the SqlDataSource in the aspx file